# jquery ui autocomplete Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, autocomplete

I have this error as displayed in the console:

> ```
> jquery-3.3.1.js:7972 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> at val (jquery-3.3.1.js:7972)
> at add (jquery-3.3.1.js:8463)
> at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8450)
> at Function.jQuery.param (jquery-3.3.1.js:8483)
> at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.js:9073)
> at $.<computed>.<computed>.source (Index:189353)
> at $.<computed>.<computed>._search (VM12 jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:6015)
> at $.<computed>.<computed>._search (VM12 jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:144)
> at $.<computed>.<computed>.search (VM12 jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:6007)
> at $.<computed>.<computed>.search (VM12 jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:144)
> ```

and it is sent when I start typing.

my script is

```
$('#pesticideTypeInput').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPesticideTypesList", "Search")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { search: $('#pesticideTypeInput').val },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    //return { label: item.PesticideTypeAR, value: item.PesticideTypeAR };
                    return item;
                }));
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

in my controller I have:

```
public JsonResult GetPesticideTypesList(string term)
{
    var pesticidesTypesList = db.PesticideTypes.Where(x => x.PesticideTypeAR.Contains(term)).ToList();
    return new JsonResult {Data=pesticidesTypesList, JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

My model class is:

```
public partial class PesticideType
{
    public PesticideType()
    {
        this.PesticidesInfoes = new HashSet<PesticidesInfo>();
    }

    public int PesticideTypePk { get; set; }
    public string PesticideTypeAR { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<PesticidesInfo> PesticidesInfoes { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Show us structure of `data` received

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: That's your server code....what is actually received in the  ajax `success`?

Comment: The console debugger is showing me undefined, so no valid data is received in success

Comment: Oh...missing `()` in `search: $('#pesticideTypeInput').val` ...should be `val()`

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what is actually sent

Comment: What’s actually happening is that I am getting an error from the server now after I renamed the param to search and it is passing the actual input.